# Why isn't a full file path required to load a dll? In what situation would this functionality be beneficial?

Tags: windows, dllimport, dll, loadlibrary

Why doesn't Windows require a full file path when calling LoadLibrary, or for CLSIDs w/ registered DLLs, etc. In what situation would someone benefit from having to fall back on the DLL Search Order to find a dll?

I mean, variables such as %SystemRoot% or %ProgramFiles% could get you to the appropriate folder, and .\ would leave you in your current directory.. So why allow the vagueness?

Comment: This probably dates back to the days before DOS supported directories.  More practically speaking, how would implicit linking work if you had to specify a full path somewhere?

Comment: Implicit linking, fair enough. I didn't consider that. I can see that making it a pain to keep track of what needs to be in which directory.

Comment: Also you have no idea where a particular dll may exist on the user's system.  For system dlls the manifest will ensure that the correct version will be used regardless of where it is actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

For explicit linking with `GetProcAddress()` I would argue that one should use the absolute path to the DLL if at all possible.

For implicit linking with .lib files then the name of the DLL has to be determined at link time which rules out absolute paths.

It is safest to put the DLL in the same directory as the executable, under %Program Files% and protected by UAC, and to use the new DLL search order.